# Share custom geo location with UIActivityView

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my App I have a place object with title, image as well as longitude and latitude. You should be able to share this place on Facebook. 
Here's the code I have so far:

```
let textToShare = self.place.placeDescription
let imageToShare = self.place.image
let longitudeToShare = self.place.longitude
let latitudeToShare = self.place.latitude
let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [(imageToShare), titleToShare, textToShare, longitudeToShare, latitudeToShare], applicationActivities: nil)                                        
self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Image and text are already put into the post but is there a way to add the longitude and latitude information to the `shareVC` so that the created Facebook post already contains this location?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the location in the text, since it's (currently) not supported to add the location directly to the post:

```
let title = self.place.placeDescription
let image = self.place.image
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Lon: \(self.place.longitude), lat: \(self.place.latitude)")

let shareViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [title, text, image], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: Yes, this adds it to the post as a text but what I mean exactly is that the location on the map will be shared, like what you can add manually within the "location" section

Comment: @Luk579 Sadly not possible, there's a nice table [here](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) of what's supported for what activity type. For Facebook it's String, AttributedString, URL and Image.